# echo the cat content into a file

Tags: bash, environment-variables, echo, cat

I have file "setting.xml" which contains some environment variable

```
<localRepository>/Users/$(whoami)/.m2/repository
```

I want to write the content of setting.xml into production.xml and replace the $(whomai) with my userid

I tried below

```
cat setting.xml | echo > production.xml
```

but not sure how can I pass the content to my echo command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
sed "s/\$(whoami)/$(whoami)/" < setting.xml >production.xml
```

The `sed` is an stream editor, and in the above, replaces the literal `$(whoami)` with the result of the command `whoami`.

Comment: Perhaps you could do for a more generic approach here and substitute all `$(..)` for their expansion?

Comment: @TomFenech maybe, but it is too dangerous for my taste, like `<cleanall>$(rm -rf /)</clanall>` :) Editing XML with sed, is entirely wrong.. ;)

Comment: Thanks, how can I replace multiple environment variable? like `$(whoami)` and `$some_path`?

Answer (score 0):

The generic approach would be :

```
eval echo `cat setting.xml | sed -r 's/([<>])/\\\\\1/g'` > production.xml
```

It may need to escape more characters than just `<` and `>`

But beware of security issues like @jm666 explained

Answer (score 0):

To replace environment variables you can use `envsubst`. The entire command would be:

```
envsubst < setting.xml > production.xml
```

You can find this command in `gettext` package. If your system don't have it installed and you are using Ubuntu, just type:

```
apt-get install gettext-base
```

You can check [envsubst manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) to know more.

Answer (score -5):

```
cat setting.xml > production.xml && sed -i "s/::whoami/$(whoami)/g"  production.xm
```

Just redirect `cat` command output with `>`
it is better to use `::whoami`  in your file instead of `$(whoami)`

Template:

```
<localRepository>/Users/::whoami/.m2/repository
```